# Dowload link in Java, Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, download

I was trying to implement a link in my webpage to download a file as CSV. The content of the file is being appended to stringbuffer and flushed to response there itself. The code below is what i tried to achieve that :

```
    public void getDownloadFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
         response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=data.csv");
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            try{
            StringBuffer sb = generateCsvFileBuffer();          
            InputStream in =  new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];

            while(in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096) != -1)
            {
                out.write(outputByte, 0, 4096);
            }
            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();            
          }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in CsvFileWriter !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error while flushing/closing fileWriter !!!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
          return;
    }
```

And the generateCsvFileBuffer() method called is where the details for the file is written. The method is as follows:

```
public StringBuffer generateCsvFileBuffer(){
        StringBuffer writer = new StringBuffer();

        writer.append("name");
        writer.append(", ");
        writer.append("age");
        writer.append(", ");
        writer.append("address");
        writer.append(", ");
        writer.append("phone no");
        writer.append("\n");

        return writer;
    }
```

The programs runs till the last line of code without any error but with no output. When the link is clicked nothing happens in the view. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to rewrite your code with Java 7's try-with-resources, for better error handling and readability.

```
package demo.spring.mvc;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class FileDownloadController {

    @RequestMapping("/download")
    public void download(Model model, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        resp.setContentType("text/csv");
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=data.csv");
        String csv = generateCsv();
        try (ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();) {
            byte[] arr = new byte[4096];
            try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(csv.getBytes("UTF-8"));) {
                for (int c; (c = in.read(arr)) != -1;) {
                    out.write(arr, 0, c);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error in CsvFileWriter!!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String generateCsv() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("name")
                .append(", ").append("age")
                .append(", ").append("address")
                .append(", ").append("phone no")
                .append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

As an added bonus, here are some thoughts about the original code.

- I changed `StringBuffer` to `StringBuilder`. Since Java 5, you can get better performance by switching your `StringBuffer`s to its not synchronized counterpart `StringBuilder`.
- Your while loop had an error because you didn't test the number of characters read (the `c` int I introduced).
- You can chain calls to `append(...)` to avoid repeating the variable name upon which the method is applied.
- I switched from calls to `System.out` to calls to `System.err` because it's mostly error handling here. It's far from perfect. You'd be better off with a logging system.

Comment: Thanku for the help but still it only shows the overlay i hav given in js when the link is clicked. Is there anything else i could do to solve the issue.

Comment: Then your problem most certainly is not with the Java code but with the configuration. Can you post web.xml or WebApplicationInitializer and Spring configuration?